# Does convergence matter in finding the best fit?

Tags: r, convergence, garch

I am trying to fit my model using garchFit function in the fGarch package, however I keep on getting this error:

```
In arima(.series$x, order = c(u, 0, v), include.mean = include.mean) :
possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1
```

Here is my code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(fGarch)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
getSymbols("SPY")
spyRets=Return.calculate(Cl(SPY),method=c('log')) #log returns
garchFit(~arma(5,5)+garch(1,1),data=tail(spyRets,500)) #gives error
```

After looking around I found this answer [Simulate ARIMA by hand](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53051/simulate-arima-by-hand)
which tells me to add in `control=list(maxit = large number)` as my solution, however that still does not work:

```
garchFit(~arma(5,5)+garch(1,1),data=tail(spyRets,500),control=list(maxit = 10000)) #still gives error
```

I have two questions. First of all I would like help to make this error disappear? Secondly, if I am trying to find the best fit, does it really matter that optim converges?

Comment: The last question on topic here, IMO.

Comment: You can try an alternative R package "rugarch" and its functions `ugarchspec` and `ugarchfit` for fitting the ARMA(5,5)-GARCH(1,1) model. There is a wider choice of optimization routines which make a failure in optimization less likely. Try specifying argument `solver="hybrid"` in `ugarchfit` for an especially "safe" way with respect to convergence of the optimization routine. Regarding the second question, yes, you need convergence. Otherwise you will get nonsense results.

Comment: I only posted here, because the previous answer was that I linked to was posted here.

Comment: I am aware of the rugarch package, but I would like to use the fGarch package if possible. Thank you for your response

Comment: Use @RichardHardy or ("at" another user) when you are responding to the particular person, otherwise we do not get notified.

Comment: Did it work? If so, perhaps I should post my comment as an answer?..

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes your suggestion worked. Just changing the package to rugarch worked. Specifying solver='hybrid' was not needed. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You can try an alternative R package "rugarch" and its functions `ugarchspec` and `ugarchfit` for specifying and fitting the ARMA(5,5)-GARCH(1,1) model, respectively. There is a wider choice of optimization routines which make a failure in optimization less likely. Try specifying argument `solver="hybrid"` in `ugarchfit` function for an especially "safe" way with respect to convergence of the optimization routine.

**2.** Regarding the second question, yes, you need convergence. Otherwise you will get nonsense results.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but thanks again

Comment: No problem! I am glad I could help.